# Problem detection when retrofit2 onFailure

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have been trying to solve the problem for 3-4 months, PLEASE read carefully and help, thank you.

I am using retrofit2 to retrieve data from the server.

```
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

OnFailure I saw something strange. First, I set the toast "internet is off" to onFailure. But then I look and the domain doesn't exist. It is giving the user the impression that your internet is off. How the internet is off, the internet is not working (the internet is on but not working) and domen doesn't exist detect and show display the appropriate toast.

Now I'm getting one toast onFailure (same message to all) even if internet is off, internet is on, internet is down and domain is not available:

```
to resolve host "(domen)": No adress...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with following reference?

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-detect-network-and-conversion-errors-in-onfailure

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. The toast in ioexception is coming even when the internet is off and the domain doesn't exist.

Comment: Is your retrofit version latest? If not, can you try to use latest one.

Comment: Yes‚ it's latest version.